# how to decide return value (true/false) of oncreate of contentprovider in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, oncreate

In my oncreate of ContentProvider, I want to return true or false depending on the following condition.

```
Context ctx = getContext();
dbhelper = new DBHelper(ctx);
database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

if (database == null) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

But doing getWritableDatabase in oncreate will lead to ANR. So if I post this to a separate thread then how will i decide return value of oncreate as database value be null.

```
Thread mCreateOrOpenDatabaseThread = new Thread (new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run() {
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }
},"CreateOrOpenDatabaseThread");
mCreateOrOpenDatabaseThread.start();
```

Can I return true explicitly? What happens when we return true or false and how will it affect my application.? what happens internally within android runtime when we return true or false in oncreate?

Comment: little advice, statement `if (database == null) {
  return false;
} else {
   return true;
 }` you can change to `return database != null;`

Comment: `In my oncreate of ContentProvider, I want to return true or false` AND `What happens when we return true or false and how will it affect my application.? `. ??? Does not match. Please tell why you would want to return true or false to begin with.

Comment: onCreate method has a return value of boolean so we have to return something

Comment: public abstract boolean onCreate();

Comment: @greenapps ....

Comment: My god you have to return a boolean. I know. But why do YOU not just return something? You use it anywhere? We still do not know for what all the fuss.

Comment: @green  oncreate method as per its declaration returns a boolean which signifies whether content provider is successfully loaded or not. So I just wanted to know the impact on return either true /false. if I return false, it means content provider not loaded, then will android call oncreate again to check if contentprovider is loaded

Comment: Is that a fact or did you forget a question mark?

Comment: @greenapps oncreate method as per its declaration returns a boolean which signifies whether content provider is successfully loaded or not. This is a fact as per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

Comment: @greenapps so if we return false it means contentprovider is not loaded properly. Then, will android call oncreate again ever??. or my content provider will never be able to supply data from sqlitedatabase in this case?

Comment: My god... I was referring to `then will android call oncreate again to check if contentprovider is loaded `. Is that a fact or did you forget a question mark was the question.

Comment: @greenapps sorry for the confusion .yes that is the question?

Comment: `If i let onCreate return false then will onCreate be called again later?`

Comment: @greenapps yes that too is a question. I want to know what is affect of returning either true or false? as for false-contentprovider is not loaded. then when will it be loaded? as for true -contentprovider is loaded but sqlitedatabase will not be available as it will be created or opened in a separate thread.or will the database be available?

Comment: You can easily find out if onCreate is called again. Just place  a log statement in it. Or do what ever to remember the call. You are experimenting isnt it? Just try all out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
public boolean func() {
    FutureTask<Boolean> ft = new FutureTask<Boolean>(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

            return true;//true or false..
        }
    });
    new Thread(ft).start();
    try {
        return ft.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you please let me know what happens when we return true or false in onCreate()? what action android takes if I return false it means my content  provider is not loaded, so will it still work to provide database to other modules???

Comment: I look through the android source code.Android will do nothing if you return  false.In fact,It never queries or saves your return value.(Is my English too bad?:()

Comment: But as per the android documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html it is mentioned that reurn value signifies whether contentprovider successfully loaded or not. So I just wanted to understand the impact of this return value on my code

Comment: `ContentProvider.this.onCreate();`I can only find it in `ContentProvider.java`.It doesn't seem that the system queries it.Maybe it will be used on higher level.